# Can I make a float number in a C program always round up

Tags: c

Can I make a float number in a C program always round up

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll find your experiences here are much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages such as [ask] in order to learn how this site works and what our expectations are before you begin posting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: How do I make a number always round up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444658/c-how-do-i-make-a-number-always-round-up)

Comment: Use `ceilf()`..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ceil()` function. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
   float val1 = 1.6;
   printf ("Round up to %.1lf\n", ceil(val1));
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Answering very low quality questions that show no effort in either writing the question or solving the problem doesn't benefit anyone, including the poster.

Comment: @KenWhite - and yet a duplicate for [tag:c] is oddly hard to find, the first one found is for objective c: [Round a float up to the next integer in objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8206291).  I guess this does it: [C: How do I make a number always round up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26444658).

Comment: @dbc: Probably true. But not being able to find a duplicate for *How do I write a more popular app than Instagram in Powershell* doesn't mean that the question has any value here. :-)